# Determining molar mass of protein from osmotic pressure

Tags: physical-chemistry, pressure

> A 299 mL solution containing 21 g of a protein in toluene had an osmotic pressure of 0.053 atm at 27 degrees Celsius. What is the molar mass (in g/mol) of the protein?

We can use the formula that

$$\Pi = iMRT$$

where $\Pi$ is the osmotic pressure, $i$ the van't Hoff factor, $M$ being the molarity, $R$ being the constant (0.08206), and $T$ being temperature in Kelvin.

Using these values, we can substitute into the equation:
0.053 atm = 1 * *M* * 0.08206 L atm/(mol * K) * 300.15 K

When we equate this to *M*, we get 
0.00215 = *M*

Now we know that there is 21 grams of toluene within the 299 mL solution. We can convert the Molarity given by multiplying it by the liters of solution there is. Therefore, 
0.299 L * 0.00215 mol/L = 0.000643 mol

Finally, to get molar mass, you simply divide the mass of toluene by the mols given:

21 g / 0.000643 mol = 32639.41 g/mol

This value, however, doesn't seem to be correct, as it is absurdly large. Can anyone help tell me what I'm doing wrong?

-*EDIT*- I was reading through the question and realized that the answer was correct, I was just thinking about it in a different sense. Thanks to everyone for their help!

Comment: Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUD_d-3ZTCs. Proteins have very large molecular mass in kilodaltons. The textbook writer, or whoever developed this question, seems to have never done any practical lab work in life.

Comment: Please provide you complete attempt, including the formula with the explanation of what is in it. Otherwise it will be very difficult to help you.

Comment: Your numerical value of $R$ is correct, but the units are wrong: $0.08206$ goes with $\pu{L atm mol-1 K-1}$, not $\pu{J K-1}$. In general it will save you some pain if you make sure to include units for all quantities (such as the concentration $M$); at the very least, it prevents careless mistakes from creeping in.

Comment: By the way I sincerely doubt that 299 mL of a solution in toluene could contain 21 g of a protein. Usually the proteins are not as much soluble in toluene.